# Sources on Inverse Spectral Theory

Tags: reference-request, spectral-theory, inverse-problems

I follow the book "Inverse Spectral Theory" by J. Pöschel and E. Trubowitz in which functional analysis is very much involved. I am curious about another approach using more real analysis and theory of ordinary differential equations. Is there any way to handle Inverse Spectral Theory in this manner? Besides textbooks, it is welcome if you suggest manuscripts, lecture notes etc.

Thank you!